# SQL Azure: Get Table Name on CREATE TABLE TRIGGER

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

In SQL Server 2008, I had a DDL Trigger that was getting the table name of a table being created with the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [tr_getName] ON DATABASE FOR CREATE_TABLE 
AS 

DECLARE @xmlEventData XML
DECLARE @TableName varchar(128)
-- Capture the event data that is created
SET @xmlEventData = eventdata()

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tNames', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DeAllocate tNames
END 

DECLARE tNames CURSOR Read_Only
FOR SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @xmlEventData.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)'))
OPEN tNames

FETCH Next FROM tNames
    INTO @TableName
...
...
```

However, in SQL Azure eventdata() is no longer supported. Is there a way to accomplish the equivalent in SQL Azure?
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

See the following pages on how to get eventdata:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781(v=sql.120).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187909(v=sql.120).aspx